# Generating element of local ring in a purely inseparable extension

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field, algebraic-curves, localization, function-fields

Let $F$ be an algebraic function field (in one variable) over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Let $F'$ be a purely inseparable extension of $F$ of degree $p$. In particular, $F'$ is a simple extension of $F$.
Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a place of $F$. Then there is only one place $\mathcal{P}'$ of $F'$ lying above $\mathcal{P}$, and $\mathcal{P}$ is totally ramified in $F'$ with ramification index $p$.

So the integral closure of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{P}} \subseteq F$ in $F'$ is simply $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{P}'}$. My question is: does there exist a generating element $\beta \in F'$ of $F'$ over $F$ that also works as a generating element of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{P}'}$ as an  $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{P}}$-module?

If $F'$ were separable over $F$, then given a basis of $F'$ over $F$ we can use the trace functional to construct a dual basis and sandwich $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{P}'}$ between the modules over $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{P}}$ generated by the basis and that generated by the dual basis, and then use the fact that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{P}}$ is a principal ideal domain to establish equality.

But what do we do if $F'$ is inseparable over $F$?

Comment: You should be aware that there is only one inseparable extension of $F$ of degree $p$, namely $F^{1/p}$.  I think this fact will help you answer your question for yourself.

Comment: Dear @Lubin, I don't believe that $F$ has only one extension of degree $p$ and I believe even less that  $F^{1/p}$ has degree $p$ over $F$.

Comment: @Lubin For example, $\mathbb{F}_{p}(X)(X^{1/p})$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p}(X)(X^{2/p})$ are distinct purely inseparable extensions of $\mathbb{F}_{p}(X)$. So while it is true that $F'^p=F$, I don't think we can conclude that "$F'=F^{1/p}$" which I am not sure is even well-defined as an expression.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, this is an algebraic function field in one variable over a finite field of characteristic $p$.  I'll be glad to see an example of two different inseparable extensions of degree $p$.

Comment: Dear @Lubin: Take $F=\mathbb  F_p(x,y)$ with $x^p+xy^{p-1}+y^p=0$. Aren't $F(\sqrt [p]x)$ and $F(\sqrt [p]y)$ different extensions of degree $p$ of $F$ ?

Comment: I must think on this: I may have been basing my argument on a false proposition.

Comment: Don't know if it is relevant, but in @Georges' example we have, for the element $u=x/y$, the equation (divide by $y^p$) $$u^p+u+1=0.$$ This implies that $u$ is algebraic over the prime field. In other words $F$ is gotten from $\Bbb{F}_p(x)$ by extending the field of constants. Furthermore, as $\Bbb{F}_p(u)$ is perfect, $u^{1/p}\in F$, and consequently those two extensions would be equal.

Comment: But, I'm sure Georges' proffered example was based on some geometric idea that I am too ignorant to reverse engineer. May be a modification works, may be not? I cannot tell.

Comment: Actually, for $p>2$, $u=-1/2$ is a solution of $u^p+u+1=0$. Therefore that degree $p$ polynomial $x^p+xy^{p-1}+y^p$ is not irreducible ($x+2y$ is a factor). Even if we try $x^p-xy^{p-1}+y^p$, when $u$ won't be an element of the prime field, that polynomial won't be absolutely irreducible with the usual geometric consequences.

Comment: Dear @Jyrki, you are absolutely right, thanks a lot for your brilliant comments. The problem is that my example was **not** inspired by geometry and displays my poor intuition for algebra not backed by geometry. But the problem remains: I'm still not convinced by our friend's Lubin's assertion (and he no longer seems to stick to his claim). We need your expertise, Jyrki: please help!

Answer (score 2):

This is not the central question you ask, but I made a claim that at least one highly respected mathematician has doubted, namely that if $F$ is a function field in one variable over a finite field, then $F^{1/p}$ is the only inseparable extension of $F$ of degree $p$. Let’s see why.

To save myself typing, I’ll write $\Bbb F_q=k$, $x^{1/p}=\xi$, $y^{1/p}=\eta$. Let’s suppose that $y$ is of degree $m$ over $k(x)$, so that $k(x,y)$ is separable of degree $m$ over $k(x)$. Then $\bigl[k(\xi,\eta):k(\xi)\bigr]=\bigl[k(x,y):k(x)\bigr]=m$. Now since $y\notin k(\xi)$, we will also have $\bigl[k(\xi,y):k(\xi)\bigr]=m$. (It may be that there are problems if $m$ is composite, but in Georges’ example, it’s certain that $y$ is of degree $p$ over $k(\xi)$.) But we now see that $k(\xi)\subset k(\xi,y)\subset k(\xi,\eta)$, and both bigger fields are of the the same degree $m$ over the smallest field. Thus the two bigger fields are equal. That is, in your notation, I’ve shown that $y^{1/p}\in F(x^{1/p})$. Similarly, $x^{1/p}\in F(y^{1/p})$.

But to put the icing on the cake, I’ll exhibit, in Georges’ proposed counterexample, $\xi\in F(\eta)=k(x,y^{1/p})$ and $\eta\in F(\xi)=k(x^{1/p},y)$.

Indeed
\begin{align}
\xi^p+\xi\eta^{p-1}+\eta^p&=0&\xi^p+\xi\eta^p/\eta+\eta^p&=0\\
\xi\eta^{p-1}&=-y-x&\xi y/\eta&=-x-y\\
\xi&=-\frac{x+y}{\eta^{p-1}}&\eta&=-\frac{\xi y}{x+y}
\end{align}

But now Georges, if $K$ is a field finitely generated
over a perfect field $k$, with transcendence degree $d$, is it not true that the field degree $[K:K^p]=p^d$ ? This is something that I have always firmly believed, though I’m sure without ever having proved it in full detail. Your proposed counterexample made me doubt perhaps fifty years’ unsupported mathematical belief.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, then if E is any purely transcendental subextension of F/K, the pth power map Fr: F -> F^p is a field isomorphism identifying E with its image E^p, so [F : E] = [F^p : E^p]. But [E : E^p] = p since K is perfect, so by factoring [F : E^p] in two ways, [F : F^p] = [E : E^p] = p. (If this works, it generalizes directly to higher tr.deg d.) Now, if F/F_0/K with F/F_0 purely inseparable of degree p, then as usual F_0 must contain F^p, so by degree reasons F_0 = F^p is unique. Applying this to an inseparable degree p extension of F then proves F^(1/p) unique.